# Symfony ZIP file is saved automatically not save as dialog box

Tags: php, symfony, zip, php-ziparchive

I have an Actionthat download select file as Zip. It works but it saves the zip file automatically. What i want is a dialog box (save as  and choose folder).

below the action:

```
public function zipDownloadAllDocumentAction( Request $request )
{
    $files = [];

    $path = $request->server->get( 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ) 
        . $request->getBasePath() 
        . $this->getParameter( "app.path.exports" );

    $documents = $request->get( 'documents' );

    array_push( $files, $path . "/" . $documents[0] );

    $zip     = new ZipArchive();
    $zipName = "Export " . time() . ".zip";
    $zip->open( $zipName, \ZipArchive::CREATE );
    foreach ( $files as $f ) {
        $zip->addFromString( basename( $f ), file_get_contents( $f ) );
    }
    $zip->close();
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse( $zipName );

    $disposition = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, $zipName );

    $response->headers->set( 'Content-Disposition', $disposition );

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: That is browser behavior and can't be manipulated with PHP as it is a server-sided language.

Comment: thanks @jrswgtr what do you suggest to me to get the dialog box

Comment: I doubt if it is even possible in all browsers. It is behaviour that you set in your browsers settings yourself. If there would be anything possible you will need a Javascript based solution. Just google for `js force save as` and you will find out.